# Discord JS Message embed dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to use a dynamic name variable inside a loop but it shows the error "EmbedMessage is not defined". Is there a way to do it?

```js
const EmbedMessage1 = {
 title: '__TITLE1__',
 description: '**First embed message**',
 //etc.
};
const EmbedMessage2 = {
 title: '__TITLE2__',
 description: '**Second embed message**',
 //etc.
};
//etc.

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
 message.channel.send({ embed: EmbedMessage[i] }).then((msg) => {
  //function
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array of embeds instead of naming your variables like that.

```js
const embeds = [
 {
  title: '__TITLE1__',
  description: '**First embed message**',
  //etc.
 },
 {
  title: '__TITLE2__',
  description: '**Second embed message**',
  //etc.
 },
];
//etc.

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
 message.channel.send({ embed: embeds[i] }).then((msg) => {
  //function
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Changing my data format to iterate, nice idea!